# Core data migrating from rdbms

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I am trying to migrate from pure sqlite (with FMDB wrapper) to core data.

My main reason is the icu problem (I have some multilingual projects - German, Spanish, Greek, Chinese) that are difficult to be searched from sqlite, as opposed with the icu built-in on core data. (NSDiacriticInsensitive | NSCaseInsensitive)

Generally I have my data (a coded book) in the following structure:

```
id
parentId
content
contentType
nContent
vieworder
```

where nContent is a diacriticinsensitive/caseinsensitive field that I need to ditch, since it slows my database very much (I have used indexes, I have used optimizations but I can't find anything to speedup the search process).

I am baffled with the core data concept -- I can understand it on a master-detail project but I can't understand how to achieve a self referenced item object --

A typical data stored with the above structure is this:

```
 Chapter A
  Chapter A.1
   Title 1
    Content #1
   Title 2
    Content #2
  Chapter A.2
 [...]
```

Where "Chapter/Title/Content" is the content field (so it varies from a small >256 string to a large block of text).

So my questions are:
* How to achieve this structure in core data entity/class (I know that it will need the self-reference relationship)
* How to find the items of each level (for example I would like to find all Title types -- that's why I have the contentType field)
* Is indexing this on the core data structures will provide me with a better indexing and better time searching rates than normal sql (I use LIKE %% structures on the nContent field)?
* Is it better to leave it on SQLITE and try finding a different indexing strategy?

Please feel free to answer any of these questions or give me at least an insight.

**UPDATE**
here is another more "realistic" example of what I mean:

```
Beginning HTML (Type: Chapter, parentid:0,id:1)
 The fundamental pieces (Type Chapter, parentid:1, id:2)
  How to begin (Type: title, parentid:2, id:3)
   [content] (Type: content, parentid:3, id:4)
  Using paragraphs (Type title, parentid:2, id:5)
   [content] (Type: content, parentid:5, id:6)
 Using Forms (Type: chapter, parentid:1, id:7)
  ... (and so on)
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Considering your clarification...

You probably want to revisit your design to see what works best.  However, a simple approach to start with would be something like...

```
ContentObject
    title: NSString
    type: whatever
    content: NSString
    subcontent: 1-to-Many relationship to ContentObject
```

In Xcode model view, you would just control-click-drag from ContentObject to itself.  A self-reference will be made.

Then, make it to-many, and give it the name "subcontent" or whatever.  Then, name the inverse relationship "parent."

Now, you have a list of objects and you can add sub object to each object, and CoreData will automatically manage the pointers back to each other.  You can also add an index for any attribute for faster searching.

If your actually content may grow large, you may want to make it an entity of its own, with a relationship to it.

Comment: Jody, the field Content represents either Chapter, or title, or the book content itself (the body text). It is a hierarchical representation of a simple book (Chapter is crude, I could mean paragraph instead -- like paragraph titles. Each is defined by the contentType variable - 0: Chapter (could also be a subchapter of the parent chapter), 1: Title, 2: Content.